# Show $-A \neq \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

For $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we denote $-A$ to be the set obtained by taking the opposite of everything in $A$. That is,
$- A : = \{-x: x \in A\}.$
Suppose that $A \neq \emptyset $ and that $A$ is bounded below. Prove that (1) $-A \neq \emptyset$ , (2) $-A$ is
bounded above, and (3) $\sup(- A) = - \inf(A)$.

Here are my attempts:
(1):
Let $x\in A$ Then by the definition of -A we have $-x \in -A$. Therefore $-A \neq \emptyset$

(2): There exists an $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq x $ $\forall x \in A$. Then by the definition of -A we have $-x \leq -a$. Thus -A is bounded below by -x.

(3): Let $y=\sup(-A)$. Then Then $b \leq y $ $\forall b \in -A$. Then by the definition of -A it follows that $-y \leq a$ $\forall a \in A$, So $-y$ is a lower bound of A. Suppose there exists some $x \in A$ such that $x <-y+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\varepsilon=y+x$. Then we have the contradiction $x<x$. Finally $-y=\inf(A)$, so $\sup(-A)=-\inf(A)$.

I'm really not sure if that proof is correct. Can you spot a mistake?

Comment: You write "Let $x=\sup(A)$" in (2).  You used the wrong word.  You meant to write $\text{inf}$

Comment: (2) needs to be adjusted, as the comment above, it looks like to write inf(A) not sup(A), but I don't think you need it, you could instead write that there exists a in the real numbers s.t. a <= x for all x in A, therefore -a => -x for all -x in -A showing that -A is bounded above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: A word of warning for your proof of (1): it's common to allow "let $x\in A$" even when $A$ could be empty, so in a sense you've actually shown "For any $x$, $x \in A \rightarrow -A \neq \emptyset$."  Some people might require you instead to write "Since $A\neq \emptyset$, there is some $x \in A$"